# I am new to APIs. Why is my request to get the JSON of one not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I already have the code below inside of a `$(document).ready(function()` inside of a click event handler that is activated once a user presses a button. Once a user presses the button, the API should be requested and the JSON from it be retrieved for me to play with. For some reason, however, every time I try to make the `$.getJSON()` request, nothing will happen. Here is all of the jQuery code I have for the website and yes, I have made sure everything else works like the event handler by testing it out on other elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#new").click(function() {
      $("body").css("background-color", changeColor());
      $("#bigContainer").css("background-color", randie);
      $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts", function(json) {

         $("#qbox").html(JSON.stringify(json));

        });
      });

    });
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Did you check your JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: Im writing it on CodePen, sadly, no errors detected ;(. What would you recommend I run it in to see errors?

Comment: The important thing is to run some diagnostics to find out what's wrong here. "Not working" isn't sufficiently detailed. Are you sure that function is being executed? Are you sure you're not getting something back? Even on CodePen you can set breakpoints and inspect variables. You can also use `console.log` to output things.

Comment: Moaead Yahya helped. I had to use https since CodePen only allows https requests. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That should generate an error in the JavaScript console of your browser, so it's odd it didn't. This is something you need to open up, it's not CodePen specific. Glad you got a solution, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you use codepin they force https and you are doing http request so this won't work because of Mixed Content policy. Please change the url to be

```
$.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts", function(json) {
```

notice the https.

Comment: No worries, please set this as the answer. Thanks and good luck. but next time please check the console it will show you the exact issue (CTRL+SHIFT+I) to open it

Comment: Can you please close this question (set it as answered) so no body waste time trying to check it. Thanks!